# How do I pass custom data into the DatabricksRunNowOperator in airflow

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, airflow, databricks

I am trying to create a DAG which uses the DatabricksRunNowOperator to run pyspark.
However I'm unable to figure out how I can access the airflow config inside the pyspark script.

```
parity_check_run = DatabricksRunNowOperator(
    task_id='my_task',
    databricks_conn_id='databricks_default',
    job_id='1837',
    spark_submit_params=["file.py", "pre-defined-param"],
    dag=dag,
)
```

I've tried accessing it via `kwargs` but that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: how job is defined - is it notebook, python file, wheel, or something else?

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this problem? I'm having the same issue, but the answers don't involve config parameters. Using PythonOperators I am able to get the config parameters using kwargs but I cannot find how to get config parameters using DatabricksRunNowOperator

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `notebook_params` argument as seen in the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-databricks/stable/_api/airflow/providers/databricks/operators/databricks/index.html#airflow.providers.databricks.operators.databricks.DatabricksRunNowOperator) .

e.g:

```
job_id=42

notebook_params = {
    "dry-run": "true",
    "oldest-time-to-consider": "1457570074236"
}

notebook_run = DatabricksRunNowOperator(
    job_id=job_id,
    notebook_params=notebook_params,

)
```

Then you can access the value via `dbutils.widgets.get("oldest-time-to-consider")` in the PySpark code.

Answer (score 0):

The `DatabricksRunNowOperator` supports different ways of providing parameters to the existing jobs, depending on how job is defined ([doc](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-databricks/stable/_api/airflow/providers/databricks/operators/databricks/index.html#airflow.providers.databricks.operators.databricks.DatabricksRunNowOperator)):

- `notebook_params` if you use notebooks - it's a dictionary of the widget name -> value. You can fetch parameters using the `dbutils.widgets.get`
- `python_params` - list of parameters that will be passed to Python task - you can fetch them via `sys.argv`
- `jar_params` - list of parameters that will be passed to Jar task. You can get them as usual for Java/Scala program
- `spark_submit_params` - list of parameters that will be passed to the `spark-submit`